# Is any condition to select upto 3 field in radio button for contact form 7

Tags: wordpress

I have 9 field in check box user can select Maximum Upto 3,   Is any condition to select upto 3 field in radio button for contact form 7

Comment: Radio buttons are basically created to allow only of them to be selected. Can you present your question in a more detail way?

Comment: is these possible Check box,  I have 9 courses so user can select Not More than 3   Please find the below URL  i have attached Screen shot  http://srmdentalcollege.ac.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/admission.jpg

Comment: Yes, you can do this via javascript. You can create function on "onchange" event of checkbox. In this function, on selection of every check box, count the number of checkboxes that are checked/selected. Once the count reaches 3, display a messages that not more courses can be selected and uncheck every other box if checked. Or alternatively you can disable every unchecked checkbox.